# What type of case is best for a Megillah?

Tags: product-recommendation, megillat-esther, protective-casing

I have a century-old Megillah (Esther) that, B"H is in quite good shape. I'd like to buy a case for it. Obviously, I don't use the megillah often during most of the year. Around the beginning of Shevat, I use it to practice my reading (occasionally, with "noise accompaniment" to simulate the Haman interruptions.) On Purim, I carry it outdoors, so I would want something waterproof. (My luck - I think 2 of the last 5 years it snowed on Purim!) The rest of the year, it stays "dormant".

What type of case would be best to preserve the parchment the longest?

- silver
- wood (any type better than another)?
- some other material

In your answer, please include why you believe your suggestion is the best solution (cheapest, keeps out moisture, etc.) and inform me if you have tried this, yourself.

Comment: Personally, I like the old-style cases which let you roll the klaf out. Almaz (the olivewood giftshop in Meah She'arim) make a beautiful one and they also do custom work. https://www.olivewoodgifts.com/product-page/olive-wood-scroll-case-priced-by-inch-size

Comment: I'd get leather.

Comment: Probably argon is the safest for long term storage

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt I like those too. But, this is not that type of megillah. FYI, the Megilla dates from Belgium circa late 1800's, I believe. It has a velvet covering on the outside of the parchment near the beginning of the megilla - enough so that when it's rolled, the velvet covers the outside of the roll.

Comment: Why fix it if it isn't broke? Seems it survived well as it is. For rain on Purim: I store my Megiloth in the tubes that whiskey comes in. (Always amuses people why I would bring whiskey to shul....)